# Text position center React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image: App screenshot. Title bar says "Albums!", rest of app is blank]
I have the following header component for my app:

```
const Header = () => {
const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;

return (
    <View style={viewStyle}>
        <Text style={textStyle}>Albums!</Text>        
    </View>
 );
};
```

And styles for this component are as follows:

```
const styles = {
viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',        
    justifyContent: 'center', //Y-axis
    alighItems: 'center', // x-axis 
    height: 60,
    paddingTop: 15,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    elevation: 2,
    position: 'relative'
},
textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20
 }
};
```

I'm learning react native from Udemy. With this code the tutor positions the text in the center of the container [Red color box]. But it doesn't work in my emulator.

Does react styles render differently in ios and android ? As the tutor was running/writing codes in mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android devices you need to add `textAlign: 'center'` to your Text Component style as well:

```
textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Example:**

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/tactless-chocolates

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
}
```